# Error using IntelliJ's Docker services when using Docker daemon in WSL through a TCP socket

Tags: docker, sockets, intellij-idea, daemon, wsl-2

I really like using IntelliJ's Docker services window, it is a great GUI to visualize and manage Docker containers, images, networks and volumes.
[image]

Recently, I started a job where Windows computers are used, but due to licensing concerns, Docker Desktop isn't an option. Because of that, Docker is ran through WSL2.

Fortunately, IntelliJ offers the option to access Docker's daemon through a TCP socket that I exposed through wsl.
[image]

For *existing* containers, this works, i can start and stop them just fine.

But when I try run configurations

[image]

or try to use the buttons to run services in other ways

[image]

I get this error telling me the Docker daemon isn't running:
[image]

```
error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filter
s=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.config-hash%22%3Atrue%2C%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dlocal-env%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The s
ystem cannot find the file specified.
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
```

From what I understand, this is due to the Docker executable pointing to a .exe that doesn't exist or isn't running.

[image]

How do I point it to the correct docker.exe if Docker is running in WSL?

Comment: Try to install/run Docker on WSL directly and switch from `TCP Socket` to `WSL` under `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Docker` The IDE will automatically load Docker from WSL. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-271117 for more details

Comment: The reason I didn't try to connect with WSL is because it gave this error:
cannot connect: org.apache.hc.core5.http.NoHttpResponseException: 127.0.0.1:80 failed to respond.

Looking at that link, the one of the latest comments describes this exact error and it has 3 upvotes, meaning others have the same issue. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you my working solution: if you use WSL I suggest you definitevely to install Docker (by APT: [here the installation guide](https://medium.com/@mikejohanson/running-docker-ce-in-wsl2-ed74dac32782)) and IntelliJ (by SNAP: `sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic`) under WSL.

I grant you that it works like a charme: IntelliJ interacts natively with Docker in the same OS environment.

About file hosted by the Windows partition, can be accessed byt the system mountpoin t `/mnt/c` .

Comment: Do you know where the docker.exe (or whatever is the Ubuntu equivalent) is? That way I could try to point to it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question. Please explain me better. PS: I added some installation guides to my post.

Comment: You said "About file hosted by the Windows partition, can be accessed by the system mountpoint /mnt/c .". What I assume is that there is probably a "docker.exe" file somewhere in my ubuntu, and therefore, somewhere in my windows files. If I could discover that file, maybe I could try pointing IntelliJ to it and successfully accessing the Docker daemon.

Comment: The docker executable is another, the one installed by the guide I provided you, available under the WSL file system.

Comment: Yes, i had already installed Docker like that on my WSL. My question is, *where* did docker get installed, I want to go into the files and search for the much needed executable.